# without factorial function to do exponent approximation in python

Tags: python, exponent, approximation

Use loops to write a program that computes the value of by using the following formula.

e ^ x = 1+x/1!+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+ ...

Notice that do not import factorial function in math module.

Sample answers:e=2.71828 and e^2=7.389056

Comment: Please add your attempt before asking for a complete code.

Comment: This seems like a homework exercise but posted an answer in case you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using factorial:

```
def calc_exp(x, n = 10):
    ' calc e^x using 1+x/1!+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+ . with a default of 10 terms (n = 10) '
                         
    term = 1                # First term is 1
    result = term           # init result to first term of series
    for k in range(1, n):
        term *= x/k         # current term is (previous term)*x/k  (i.e. effectively x^k/k!)
        result += term      # add current term
        
    return result
```

**Test**

```
for x in [1, 2]:
    print(f'e^{x} = {calc_exp(x)}') # Use print('e^{} = {}'.format(x, calc_exp(x)))
                                    # for earlier than Python 3.6
```

**Output**

```
e^1 = 2.7182815255731922
e^2 = 7.3887125220458545
```

Comment: File "<ipython-input-5-42f2a4d801d9>", line 13
    print(f'e^{x} = {calc_exp(x)}')
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Ken are you using Python 3.6+ i.e. need it for string interpolation?

Comment: @Ken added mod to show how to perform it without Python 3.6+.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the accumulate() function (from itertools) to build the series with your specified number of terms, then use the sum() function to add them all up:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def exp(x,terms=20):
    return sum(accumulate(range(1,terms+1),lambda t,i:t*x/(i-1)))

print(exp(1)) # 2.7182818284590455

print(exp(2)) # 7.389056098925863
```

It can also be done recursively (without libraries):

```
def exp(x,terms=20,f=1):
    return 1 + x/f if f==terms else 1 + x*exp(x,terms,f+1)/f
```

The way the recursive function works is by building the  series progressively going backward from the last term. This approach converges faster than adding terms (probably because it doesn't lose as much precision on each iteration)

*from depest recursion level up to initial function call:*

```
f=20: 1 + x/f          F20: 1 + x/20

f=19: 1 + x * F20 / f  F19: 1 + x * (1 + x/20) / 19
                            1 + x/19 + x^2/(20*19)

f=18: 1 + x * F19 / f  F18: 1 + x * (1 + x/19 + x^2/(20*19)) / 18
                            1 + x/18 + x^2/(19*18) + x^3/(20*19*18)

f=17: 1 + x * F18 / f  F17: 1 + x/17 + x^2/(18*17) + x^3/(19*18*17) + ...

...

f=3 : 1 + x * F4  / f   F3: 1 + x/3  + x^2/(4*3)   + x^3/(5*4*3)    + ... 

f=2 : 1 + x * F3  / f   F2: 1 + x/2  + x^2/(3*2)   + x^3/(4*3*2)    + ... 

f=1 : 1 + x * F2  / f  exp: 1 + x/1  + x^2/(2*1)   + x^3/(3*2*1)    + ...
```

Or, if you don't like recursion, an iterative solution is also possible:

```
def exp(x,terms=20):
    result = 1
    for f in range(terms,0,-1):
        result = 1 + x * result / f
    return result
```

*Note that in all cases, as x gets larger, you will need more terms to get the desired precision*

Comment: we can't use any import function